# Group consecutive rows in a data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I can't find a solution for this simple problem. 
I have a data frame like this:

```
df = data.table(X1 = 1:12, X2 = LETTERS[1:12])
```

I would like to create a new variable named `group` where I would like to group consecutive rows by 3. For example: rows 1-3, will be group0, rows 4-6 will be group2 and so on.

Result expected:

```
    X1 X2 group
 1:  1  A     0
 2:  2  B     0
 3:  3  C     0
 4:  4  D     1
 5:  5  E     1
 6:  6  F     1
 7:  7  G     2
 8:  8  H     2
 9:  9  I     2
10: 10  J     3
11: 11  K     3
12: 12  L     3
```

Comment: I'm not well versed in data.table, but this works: `df$group<-((df$X1-1)%/%3)+1`

Comment: Translating to data.table: `df[, group := (1:.N - 1) %/% 3]`.

Comment: @Gregor perfect, you might want to formulate an answer with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mod operator `%/%` is an easy way to do things like this:

```
df[, group := (1:.N - 1) %/% 3]
df
#    X1 X2 group
# 1:  1  A     0
# 2:  2  B     0
# 3:  3  C     0
# 4:  4  D     1
# 5:  5  E     1
# 6:  6  F     1
# 7:  7  G     2
# 8:  8  H     2
# 9:  9  I     2
#10: 10  J     3
#11: 11  K     3
#12: 12  L     3
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `rep`

```
df[, group := rep(1:(.N / 3) - 1, each = 3)]
df
#    X1 X2 group
# 1:  1  A     0
# 2:  2  B     0
# 3:  3  C     0
# 4:  4  D     1
# 5:  5  E     1
# 6:  6  F     1
# 7:  7  G     2
# 8:  8  H     2
# 9:  9  I     2
#10: 10  J     3
#11: 11  K     3
#12: 12  L     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here one's way to do it.

```
consecutive_groups <- function(df, group_length = 3) {
  n_groups <- if_else(nrow(df) %% group_length == 0L, 
                      nrow(df) / group_length, 
                      as.integer(nrow(df) / group_length) + 1 )
  df %>% mutate(row_number = row_number(), 
                group = ntile(row_number, n_groups) - 1) %>% 
         select(-row_number)
}




 consecutive_groups(df, 3)
   #     X1 X2 group
   # 1   1  A     0
   # 2   2  B     0
   # 3   3  C     0
   # 4   4  D     1
   # 5   5  E     1
   # 6   6  F     1
   # 7   7  G     2
   # 8   8  H     2
   # 9   9  I     2
   # 10 10  J     3
   # 11 11  K     3
   # 12 12  L     3
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case with a quick function:

```
   group <- function(dt,groupsize)
    {
      if(nrow(dt) %% groupsize != 0){
        print("Groupsize must be divisor of nrow!")
        return()
      }
    return(cbind(dt,data.frame(group=unlist(lapply(1:(nrow(dt) / groupsize),function(i){rep(i,groupsize)}))))))
    }
```

Comment: The `lapply` is just adding inefficiency and complication. `unlist(lapply(1:(nrow(dt) / groupsize),function(i){rep(i,groupsize)}))` is a long way of writing `rep(1:(nrow(dt) / groupsize), each = groupsize)`.

Comment: Oh. Didn't know about this option in rep, thank you very much.